# push segue won't draw UITabBarController, but modal segue will. Am I missing something?

Tags: ios5, uitabbarcontroller, push, storyboard, segue

I have been pouring over this site for hours trying to find an answer to this issue, but have been unable to resolve it.  The problem is as follows:

I have a UITableViewController that uses a push segue to push a `UITabBarController` onto the stack.  The `UITabBarController` has relationships with 4 `UITableViewControllers`.

When I change the segue to modal, the first UITableViewControllers associated with the `UITabBarController` displays as expected, except of course without the Navigation Bar.  When I select push segue, the issue is reversed: the navigation bar appears with the proper name of the `UITabBarController` and the custom buttons I created...but neither the tab bar nor the contents of the first tab display - just black.

Is there something special I need to do to get the contents of the UITabBarController to display when a push segue is used?

I've tried embedding one of the `UITableViews` that the `UITabBarController` is related to in a `UINavigationController`, but that made no difference.

The basic structure of my current app is:

> UIView->(modal
>   segue)->UINavigationController->(relationship)->UITableViewController->(push segue)->UITabBarController->(relationship)[4 UITableViewControllers)

Thanks!

Comment: Also, at this point I don't need to pass any data between views - I'm just trying to get the mockup to work before adding actual useful functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually Apple encourages Users **not** to use UITabbarcontroller in a Navigationcontroller. One simply doesn't do that. That's why you get this wired behavior. Try to redesign your App so that this is no longer necessary or otherwise use modal Segue and create a new Navigationcontroller in Tabbarcontroller.

There's also a third option to create a custom Tabbarcontroller, but I personally wouldn't do that because it is not intended to be done by Apple either and it's quite a bit of Work.

There may be some other solutions but I didn't find anything simple enough to try out, so I used modal Segue in my App...

Comment: Thanks.  I am not sure if this is related, but I notice if I subclass a custom NavigationController OR a custom TabBarController using only the basic auto-generated class files with NO changes for either, then I will end up with black screen where the view should draw.  If I just use the base classes of UINavigationController and UITabBarController, then everything works fine.

The problem is, I want to customize the right side button on the nav bar and it'd be really convenient if I could do that just once in the subclass of UINavigationController...

Comment: Soyy, I can't help you out there, because I never tried subclassing either TabBarController or Navigationcontroller

Comment: @sensslen - Just curious, where do you find such information as what Apple discourages and encourages as you have pointed out about UITabBars and NavControllers, in the User Interface Guidelines?  if so, Can you point me in the right directions?

Comment: Phu, good question! Actually at the moment I don't remember where I found that, but the Fact that the Option to do so is not present within XCode implies so... If I find my source, I will post it.